# Overcoming AWS gateway time limit for Spacy applications with Long text

Tags: aws-lambda, nlp, aws-api-gateway, spacy, amazon-sagemaker

I have deployed a NLP model based on Spacy on AWS. The general issue that I am facing is the timeout issue when the text is too long.

The application is deployed as an API on AWS which is first triggered by AWS API gateway, then AWS Lambda and lastly a Sagemaker Endpoint for inference. When the text is too long, it times out likely due to the 29seconds limit on the API gateway.

I have tried chunking long documents and parallelizing the processing as such:

```
for doc in clf.pipe(cleaned_text_chunks, n_process = 2, batch_size = 64):
    docs.append(doc)
ner_output = Doc.from_docs(docs)
```

But this doesn't result in any speed-up even with different n_processes. I have tried increasing the processing power using a ml.m4.2xlarge machine Still, it doesn't make a difference. What are the possible ways to speed this up? Thanks a lot in advance.

Here's the spacy configuration as requested:

```
[paths]
train = null
dev = null
vectors = null
init_tok2vec = null

[system]
gpu_allocator = null
seed = 0

[nlp]
lang = "xx"
pipeline = ["tok2vec","ner"]
batch_size = 1000
disabled = []
before_creation = null
after_creation = null
after_pipeline_creation = null
tokenizer = {"@tokenizers":"spacy.Tokenizer.v1"}

[components]

[components.ner]
factory = "ner"
incorrect_spans_key = "incorrect_spans"
moves = null
scorer = {"@scorers":"spacy.ner_scorer.v1"}
update_with_oracle_cut_size = 100

[components.ner.model]
@architectures = "spacy.TransitionBasedParser.v2"
state_type = "ner"
extra_state_tokens = false
hidden_width = 64
maxout_pieces = 2
use_upper = true
nO = null

[components.ner.model.tok2vec]
@architectures = "spacy.Tok2VecListener.v1"
width = ${components.tok2vec.model.encode.width}
upstream = "*"

[components.tok2vec]
factory = "tok2vec"

[components.tok2vec.model]
@architectures = "spacy.Tok2Vec.v2"

[components.tok2vec.model.embed]
@architectures = "spacy.MultiHashEmbed.v2"
width = ${components.tok2vec.model.encode.width}
attrs = ["NORM","PREFIX","SUFFIX","SHAPE"]
rows = [5000,2500,2500,2500]
include_static_vectors = true

[components.tok2vec.model.encode]
@architectures = "spacy.MaxoutWindowEncoder.v2"
width = 256
depth = 8
window_size = 1
maxout_pieces = 3

[corpora]

[corpora.dev]
@readers = "spacy.Corpus.v1"
path = ${paths.dev}
max_length = 0
gold_preproc = false
limit = 0
augmenter = null

[corpora.train]
@readers = "spacy.Corpus.v1"
path = ${paths.train}
max_length = 0
gold_preproc = false
limit = 0
augmenter = null

[training]
dev_corpus = "corpora.dev"
train_corpus = "corpora.train"
seed = ${system.seed}
gpu_allocator = ${system.gpu_allocator}
dropout = 0.1
accumulate_gradient = 1
patience = 16000
max_epochs = 0
max_steps = 20000
eval_frequency = 200
frozen_components = []
annotating_components = []
before_to_disk = null

[training.batcher]
@batchers = "spacy.batch_by_words.v1"
discard_oversize = false
tolerance = 0.2
get_length = null

[training.batcher.size]
@schedules = "compounding.v1"
start = 100
stop = 1000
compound = 1.001
t = 0.0

[training.logger]
@loggers = "spacy.ConsoleLogger.v1"
progress_bar = false

[training.optimizer]
@optimizers = "Adam.v1"
beta1 = 0.9
beta2 = 0.999
L2_is_weight_decay = true
L2 = 0.01
grad_clip = 1.0
use_averages = false
eps = 0.00000001
learn_rate = 0.001

[training.score_weights]
ents_f = 1.0
ents_p = 0.0
ents_r = 0.0
ents_per_type = null

[pretraining]

[initialize]
vectors = ${paths.vectors}
init_tok2vec = ${paths.init_tok2vec}
vocab_data = null
lookups = null
before_init = null
after_init = null

[initialize.components]

[initialize.components.ner]

[initialize.components.ner.labels]
@readers = "spacy.read_labels.v1"
path = "/labels/ner.json"

[initialize.tokenizer]
```

Here's the flask launch script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# This file implements the scoring service shell. You don't necessarily need to modify it for various
# algorithms. It starts nginx and gunicorn with the correct configurations and then simply waits until
# gunicorn exits.
#
# The flask server is specified to be the app object in wsgi.py
#
# We set the following parameters:
#
# Parameter                Environment Variable              Default Value
# ---------                --------------------              -------------
# number of workers        MODEL_SERVER_WORKERS              the number of CPU cores
# timeout                  MODEL_SERVER_TIMEOUT              60 seconds

from __future__ import print_function
import multiprocessing
import os
import signal
import subprocess
import sys

cpu_count = multiprocessing.cpu_count()

# model_server_timeout = os.environ.get('MODEL_SERVER_TIMEOUT', 60)
model_server_timeout = 3600
model_server_workers = int(os.environ.get('MODEL_SERVER_WORKERS', cpu_count))

def sigterm_handler(nginx_pid, gunicorn_pid):
    try:
        os.kill(nginx_pid, signal.SIGQUIT)
    except OSError:
        pass
    try:
        os.kill(gunicorn_pid, signal.SIGTERM)
    except OSError:
        pass

    sys.exit(0)

def start_server():
    print('Starting the inference server with {} workers.'.format(model_server_workers))


    # link the log streams to stdout/err so they will be logged to the container logs
    subprocess.check_call(['ln', '-sf', '/dev/stdout', '/var/log/nginx/access.log'])
    subprocess.check_call(['ln', '-sf', '/dev/stderr', '/var/log/nginx/error.log'])

    nginx = subprocess.Popen(['nginx', '-c', '/opt/program/nginx.conf'])
    gunicorn = subprocess.Popen(['gunicorn',
                                 '--timeout', str(model_server_timeout),
                                 '-k', 'gevent',
                                 '-b', 'unix:/tmp/gunicorn.sock',
                                 '-w', str(model_server_workers),
                                 'wsgi:app'])

    signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, lambda a, b: sigterm_handler(nginx.pid, gunicorn.pid))

    # If either subprocess exits, so do we.
    pids = set([nginx.pid, gunicorn.pid])
    while True:
        pid, _ = os.wait()
        if pid in pids:
            break

    sigterm_handler(nginx.pid, gunicorn.pid)
    print('Inference server exiting')

# The main routine just invokes the start function.

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start_server()


The nginx.conf script:
```

```
  worker_processes 1;
  daemon off; # Prevent forking


  pid /tmp/nginx.pid;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

  events {
    # defaults
  }

  http {
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log combined;
    proxy_connect_timeout  3600s;
    proxy_send_timeout  3600s;
    proxy_read_timeout  3600s;
    upstream gunicorn {
      server unix:/tmp/gunicorn.sock;
    }

    server {
      listen 8080 deferred;
      client_max_body_size 5m;

      keepalive_timeout 3600s;
      proxy_connect_timeout  3600s;
      proxy_send_timeout  3600s;
      proxy_read_timeout  3600s;

      location ~ ^/(ping|invocations) {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header Connection "";
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass http://gunicorn;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_connect_timeout  3600s;
        proxy_send_timeout  3600s;
        proxy_read_timeout  3600s;
      }

      location / {
        return 404 "{}";
      }
    }
  }
```

```
The endpoint configuration:

[![AWS endpoint config][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cjzw0.png
```

Comment: Can you upload the inference model definition code? You can configure the timeout parameters. Let's see what there is to be able to configure.

Comment: do you mean on Sagemaker or spacy? I don't see any timeout configuration on sagemaker. The spacy model was trained on default settings in Prodigy. It is almost certain that the timeout is due to AWS API gateway. So it seems like I have to either modify something on AWS or speed up spacy's inference speed

Comment: @GiuseppeLaGualano I see what you mean now. Have added the config. Appreciate any suggestions!

Comment: I didn't mean the spacy component configuration. I would like to see the sagemaker component (model) configuration. Somewhere did you define the endpoint deployment? The endpoint reports to a model, how is the model defined? Where do you point to your inference script and/or container? I mean all the sagemaker code. Thank you

Comment: How long are your documents? Using a tok2vec it would be very weird to have a request take 30s. Are you getting whole books or something?

Comment: Re @GiuseppeLaGualano, the sagemaker endpoint points to a container which is a flask app. So there is no sagemaker code per se. Let me add the code for starting the app, the configuration and the endpoint configuration. Let me know if more information is needed

Comment: @polm23 do you mean tok2vec could be too slow? my documents could be hundreds of pages long

Comment: OK, that makes sense then. You might want to consider doing the job in the background and just returning an acknowledgement or something. If you need to return it right away, you should split the document up and send it to many processes.

Comment: @polm23 Yes, my last resort is to do asynchronous inference. But the ideal scenario is to return right away, that's why I am hoping to speed this up somehow. How would you parallelize this then? I have tried using spacy to do so but I don't see any speedup. Not sure if it's insufficient of resources or I am not setting certain config right

Comment: Parallelization in spaCy does not split up single Doc processing - you need to split up your text before you pass it to spaCy. For spaCy or most NLP pipelines normal text is like a page or two at most, and a few sentences is typical.

Comment: Yes I have tried splitting it up and use spacy's parallel processing (see the first code block). Doesn't speed things up for some reason

Comment: To me the solution isn't really to "make spaCy run faster". What you have here is a classic case of The Cloud causing issues that didn't exist on-prem... Anyway, I would be looking at the 202 HTTP Response Code, commonly used in cases where it will take a long time to process a request. I am not familiar with the particulars of AWS Gateway but I would guess there's support for 202.